# How to count the strings in a map?

Tags: c++, class, dictionary, methods, count

A method of a class returns a map of string and objects of another class. I want to count the number of strings? How can I do that?

This is the representation of the method

```
class b{
public:
std::map<std::string, ClassA*>& methodA();
};
```

I am calling this method with

```
auto a = pointer_of_class_B ->methodA();
```

This will return a map. How can I count the number of strings in this map?

Comment: Find the size of the map? Using `std::map::size`

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/size ?

Comment: On a side note: `methodA()` is returning a *reference*, but `auto` does not infer references, so `auto a = pointer_of_class_B->methodA();` will deduce `a` as `std::map<...>` rather than `std::map<...>&`, and so `a` will be a *copy* of the returned `map`. Use `auto &a = ...` instead to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the std::map::size function to find how many elements are in the map.

Cpp Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/size

Answer (score 2):

> How can I count the number of strings in this map?

You can use [std::map::size](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/size/) member function of `std::map` as shown below:

```
//---------------------------------------------------vvvv--->use size member function of std::map
std::cout << "number of strings inside map is " << a.size() << '\n';
```

This works as `size` member function gives the number of elements inside the `map` which in your case is equal to the number of strings in the `map`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [std:map cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)